# Reading a nodejs promise with firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I'm trying to read a value from firebase using nodejs. I got the reading part working. However I cannot get the value to be output.

I'm pretty new to nodejs and I believe I'm doing something wrong with reading promises.

Here is my code

```
#index.js
var firebase = require('./firebase');

firebase.readValue(data => {
  console.log('--- output value')
  console.log(data);
})


#firebase.js
(function(){
    var admin = require('firebase-admin');
    var serviceAccount = require('./keys/<keyfile>');

    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL: '<url>'
    });

    module.exports = {
        readValue: function(){
            var firebase = admin.database().ref("nemo/garage/status");
                firebase.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
                console.log("----------- reading from firebase...")
                console.log(snapshot.val())
                return snapshot;
            }, function(error){
               console.log('error')
            })
        }
    }
}());
```

When I do `node index.js` I get `----------- reading from firebase...` but not the `--- output value` from index.js and it just hangs there.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in reading this promise ?

my node version is - v8.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `once()` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  This causes your `readValue` to return immediately with no value.  The function you passed to `once()` will be invoked some time later.

If you want to make a function that queries Realtime Database (or does anything with async work), it should return a promise so that the caller can use `then()` on it to get the result whenever it becomes ready.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Doug, does that mean, I need to convert `readValue` function to a Promise ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "convert".  It will be easiest if it returns a promise so that the caller can decide how to wait for the work to complete.

Comment: thanks, I think I'm bit confused on how to return a promise, (I started node 2 days ago and I might be missing a simple thing here). Would you be able to give me a code sample or a link for me to have a look, cheers

Comment: once() returns a promise.  You could return that promise.

Comment: ah, I see, thanks. Will try that soon :), thanks again for the help

Comment: thanks @Daug, got it working by having this line - `return  firebase.once("value");`